# @Contract annotation with return value and changed and unchanged parameters

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations

Is it possible to annotate this function correctly?

```
@NotNull
@Contract"_, _ -> new")  // Does not say input is unchanged
@Contract(pure = true, "_, _, _ -> new") //  not possible
Rectangle exampleMethod(@NotNull List input, @NotNull List output) {
    output.clear();
    output.addAll(input);
    do something amazing with output;
    return new Rectangle (x1, y1, w, h); 
};
```

The list input will remain untouched (pure), the list output will be new and !null and the return value will also always be !null also.

I did not find a way to express that the list input will remain untouched and the the list output will be returned with a new value.

I this a pure method at all? I would assume the method is not pure as the 2nd parameter is changed, even though that is expected.

Using -> new means I get a new return value. I would like to express, I change the output parameter to a new value. The documentation on new is a bit unclear to me.

I found the following documentation:

- [Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/contract-annotations.html)
- [Intellij Blog Post 2013](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/10/better-control-flow-analysis-with-contract-annotations-and-intellij-idea-13/)
- [Intellij Blog Post 2018](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/05/intellij-idea-2018-2-eap3-advanced-contract-annotations-and-more/)

Comment: Your code is not syntactically correct.  It declares a local variable with the same name as a formal parameter.  Should that line be an assignment to the formal parameter?  (In that case, the second parameter is not changed, but merely reassigned.)

Comment: Thanks for this. Of course I can not assign a new object. I corrected it.